# Influence on proxy generation in Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I was wondering whether the following would be possible using Doctrine 2.4.

Suppose we have an entity that looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table
 */
class SomeEntity {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $some_really_long_named_id;
    public function getSomeReallyLongNamedId() { return $this->some_really_long_named_id; }
}
```

Since we work in IT and we're lazy, I added this method:

```
public function getId() { return $this->some_really_long_named_id; }
```

When this entity is proxied and we call `getId()` on the proxy of this entity, the entity is lazy loaded. Which is weird, as that doesn't happen when we call `getSomeReallyLongNamedId()`.

Apparently this has to do with some magic inside Doctrine's proxy objects. The generated proxy methods look like this:

```
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getId()
    {

        $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'getId', array());

        return parent::getId();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getSomeReallyLongNamedId()
    {
        if ($this->__isInitialized__ === false) {
            return  parent::getSomeReallyLongNamedId();
        }


        $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'getSomeReallyLongNamedId', array());

        return parent::getSomeReallyLongNamedId();
    }
```

Is there any way to influence the `ProxyGenerator` to make sure that when the `getId()` method is called, it doesn't imply a lazy-load?

Answer (score 0):

I know your question i quite old, but i'm searching a solution to the same problem.

I found a way to do disable the direct lazy-load with annotations :

```
/** @Id **/
protected $id;

/** @IdGetter **/
public function getId() { 
 ...
}
```

that will force a initialization test in the proxy class :

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getId()
{
    if ($this->__isInitialized__ === false) {
       return  parent::getId();
    }

    $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'getId', array());

    return parent::getId();
}
```

**EDIT #1**

The getId() method MUST be less than 4 lines (@see in ProxyGenerator.php method isShortIdentifierGetter()) to be detected as an identity getter.

Comment: I can't find any reference on the `IdGetter` annotation. There is this [feature request](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-687), where it states it is implemented. However, in the current [annotation class directory](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping) there is no mention of it.

I can't get it to work. Probably because my case is different: I'm using a second getter besides the default `getId` method.